# How to modify the object and convert to array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, nested-object

How to change object to array of objects in javascript.

How to modify object and get the new aray of objects in javascript

Expected Result should be as input object weeks x 2 times (4 objects in output array)

for each item.
In Expected Output,
group key represents the weeks columns array,
should create a arraylist of each item desc, and interval qty per week

```
function createObject(obj){
  const results = [];
  for (var itm of obj.items) {
    group: Object.values(obj.options).map((opt, index)=>opt.start+"-"+opt.end)
  }

}


var obj =  {
  options: {
    w1: {start:"Jan",end: "1"},
    w2: {start:"Feb", end: "1"}
  },
  intervals: {
    t1: {begin: "1", end: "2", totalqty: 2,totalamt: 200},
    t2: {begin: "4", end: "7", totalqty: 3, totalamt: 300},
  }
  items: [
    {
      name: "s1",
      desc: "sample1",
      w1: {t1: {qty:0},t2: {qty:1}},
      w2: {t1: {qty:1},t2: {qty:2}}
    }
    {
      name: "s2",
      desc: "sample2",
      w1: {t1: {qty:0},t2: {qty:0}},
      w2: {t1: {qty:0},t2: {qty:1}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    group:"Jan 1", // represents w1
    columns: [
      {
      col: 'desc',
      value: 'sample1' // item.desc
      },    
      {
       col: '1-2', // represents t1
       value: 0   , // represents t1.qty
      },
      {
       col: '4-7', // represents t2   
       value: 1 // represents w1.t2.qty   
      }   
    ]
  },
  {
    group:"Feb 1", // represents w2
    columns: [
      {
      col: 'desc',
      value:'sample1' 
      },
      {
      col: '1-2', // represents t1
        value:1   , // represents t1.qty
      },
      {
       col: '4-7', // represents t2
        value:2 ,// represents t2.qty
      }
   ]
  },
  {
   group:"Jan 1", 
    columns: [
      {
      col: 'desc',
       value:'sample2' 
      },    
      {
      col: '1-2', 
        value:0, 
      },
      {
       col: '4-7', 
        value:0 
      }   
    ]
  },
  {
   group:"Feb 1",
    columns: [
      {
     col: 'desc',
       value:'sample2' 
      },
      {
       col: '1-2',
        value:0   ,
      },
      {
       col: '4-7',
        value:1,
      }
   ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. It produces the expected result

```
function createObject(obj){
    return obj.items.map((item) => {
      return Object.keys(obj.options).map((optKey) => {
        const option = obj.options[optKey];
        const items = {
            'group' : `${option.start} ${option.end}`,
            'columns': [{col: 'desc', value: item.desc}]
        };
        const intervals = item[optKey];
        Object.keys(intervals).forEach((interval) => {
            items.columns.push({
                col: `${obj.intervals[interval].begin}-${obj.intervals[interval].end}`,
                value: intervals[interval].qty
            })  
        })
        return items;
      })
    });
}
```